# Fourier transform of a bounded function

Tags: fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions

This should really be well-known, but I was not able to find a definite answer to this question:

*Is the Fourier transform of a bounded function always a borel measure (i.e. an order 0 distribution)?*

In some sense, the distributional order corresponds to the order of a bounding polynomial and a bounded function can be bounded by an order zero polynomial. But I could not find any reference.

If the above statement is false, what is a counterexample?

If the statement is true: How does bounded variation correspond to all this? I.e. are there criterions for the Fourier transform to be of bounded variation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is no : Fourier transform of the signum function is a constant times the distribution  $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 1_{|x|>\epsilon}/x$, of order $1$, also known as the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of $1/x$. Another keyword is [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform).

Comment: I suppose, continuity of the function does not help either?

Comment: No, because modifying the signum function, say on [-1,1], to render it       continuous (or even smooth), would just add an $L^1$ function to it, hence a $C_0$ function to its Fourier transform. On the other hand continuous [positive definite][1] functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are exactly the Fourier transforms of finite positive measures, by Bochner's theorem.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function